# MVT Deductions: Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Suppose that $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$
and that $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Deduce from the mean value theorem
that $f$ is decreasing on $[a, b]$.

(b) Prove that $\ln(x) < x-1$, for $x>1$

(c) Prove that $\ln(x) \le x-1$ for all $x>0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show $c$. All boils down to this famous inequality

$$ \boxed{e^x \geq x + 1} $$

To show $c$, notice $ e^x \geq x + 1 \implies x \geq \ln(x + 1 ) $. Now, put $y = x+1 $. Then

$$ y - 1 \geq \ln(y) $$

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is standard: pick $x_1<x_2$ and $c \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=f'(c)(x_2-x_1)$. The right-hand side is $\leq 0$, therefore $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$, and this shows that $f$ is decreasing.